# Pythonic way to get n elements at time from list

Tags: python, list, range, slice

There are similar questions but i didn't find a clean answer for what i think is simple.

I want to get once the first 1000 elements of a list, then the first 2000 ecc...

```
for i in range(1000, len(l1), 1000):
     a = l1[:i]
```

but obviously won't work if len(l1) % 1000 != 0 or if len(l1) < 1000.
What is an easy solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/2301450)

Comment: 1) Why do you think this won't work for lists that have more or less a multiple of 1000 number of elements
2) are you sure the `range` should start at 1000 and not 0?